# Enumerating over an NSMutableDictionary -- can't access object properties from within the loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, for-in-loop, fast-enumeration

I have an NSMutableDictionary, `analyzedPxDictionary`, containing a bunch of Pixel objects (a custom class I created). Among other things, Pixel objects contain an NSArray property called `rgb`. That array will always contain three NSNumber objects, with integer values corresponding to the pixel's rgb values.

I'm now trying to enumerate over the `analyzedPxDictionary` using fast enumeration. However, It seems like I'm not able to access Pixel objects' properties from within the loop. I have declared `rgb` to be a synthesized property so that I can access it using dot syntax. But when I try to do so from within the loop, the program crashes, giving me an error like the following:

`'-[NSCFString rgb]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa90bb50'`

Here's an example of the code that produces that error:

```
for (Pixel *px in analyzedPxDictionary) {
    printf("r: %i, g: %i, b: %i",[[px.rgb objectAtIndex:0] integerValue], [[px.rgb objectAtIndex:1] integerValue], [[px.rgb objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]);
}
```

I've tried setting a break point on that `printf` line in order to inspect `px`. While `rgb` is listed as one if its properties and correctly described as an instance of NSArray, it doesn't seem to contain any objects.

I believe that I'm initializing `rgb` correctly. To explain, consider the following code:

```
NSString *key;
for (Pixel *px in analyzedPxDictionary) {
    key = [px description];
}

Pixel *px = [analyzedPxDictionary objectForKey:key];
printf("\nr: %i, g: %i, b: %i",[[px.rgb objectAtIndex:0] integerValue], [[px.rgb objectAtIndex:1] integerValue], [[px.rgb objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]);
```

This successfully prints the correct values to the console.

So why can't I access the `rgb` property from within the `forin` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fast enumeration of NSDictionaries gives you each key, not each value. So you'd need to do:

```
for (NSString *key in analyzedPxDictionary) 
{
    Pixel *px = [analyzedPxDictionary objectForKey:key];
    printf("r: %i, g: %i, b: %i",[[px.rgb objectAtIndex:0] integerValue], [[px.rgb objectAtIndex:1] integerValue], [[px.rgb objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Gotta love easy fixes :)